# Serialize/Deserialize objects using Protocol Buffer

Tags: serialization, deserialization, protocol-buffers

This is what I want to achieve:

1. Model an object using google protocol buffer in Proc #1
2. Serialize that object using proto-buf and send it over posix message
   queue.
3. Read and deserialize the stream into a like model in Proc #2, also using 
   protocol buffer.

In other words:

Object in Proc #1 --> Serialize --> Send to Posix MQ --> Receive from Posix MQ --> Deserialize --> Object in Proc #2

The catch is Proc #1 and Proc #2 may be completely different language platforms. Proc #1 will usually be C++ complied with g++. But Proc #2 can be anything: Python, Java etc... (Only limited by support for Protobuf).

Now I want to ascertain if Protocol Buffer's serialization strategy is universal enough for the deserialization to work on any language codebase?

Answer (score 0):

YES, that is guaranteed. Protobuf defines how to serialize and deserialize the data, and Protobuf libs of any language should implement the same serialization protocol.

Also that's why GRPC can work with many languages, e.g. you can have a C++ GRPC server, and a Java GRPC client.